# SSH to multiple hosts at once

Tags: ssh

I have a script which loops through a list of hosts, connecting to each of them with SSH using an RSA key, and then saving the output to a file on my local machine - this all works correctly. However, the commands to run on each server take a while (~30 minutes) and there are 10 servers. I would like to run the commands in parallel to save time, but can't seem to get it working. Here is the code as it is now (working):

```
for host in $HOSTS; do
    echo "Connecting to $host"..
    ssh -n -t -t $USER@$host "/data/reports/formatted_report.sh"
done
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: Take a look at [parallel ssh](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) and [mass parallel ssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpssh/), just to name a couple of projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried using `&` to send the SSH commands to the background, but I abandoned this because after the SSH commands are completed, the script performs some more commands on the output files, which need to have been created.

Using `&` made the script skip directly to those commands, which failed because the output files were not there yet. But then I learned about the **wait** command which waits for background commands to complete before continuing. Now this is my code which works:

```
for host in $HOSTS; do
    echo "Connecting to $host"..
    ssh -n -t -t $USER@$host "/data/reports/formatted_report.sh" &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 6):

You should add `&` to the end of the ssh call, it will run on the background.

```
for host in $HOSTS; do
    echo "Connecting to $host"..
    ssh -n -t -t $USER@$host "/data/reports/formatted_report.sh" &
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this but it is close to the answer (see what I posted) as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try massh http://m.a.tt/er/massh/. This is a nice tool to run ssh across multiple hosts.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hypertable](http://www.hypertable.com) project has recently added a multi-host ssh tool. This tool is built with libssh and establishes connections and issues commands *asynchronously* and *in parallel* for maximum parallelism. See [Multi-Host SSH Tool](http://hypertable.com/documentation/tools/ht_ssh/) for complete documentation. To run a command on a set of hosts, you would run it as follows:

```
$ ht ssh host00,host01,host02 /data/reports/formatted_report.sh
```

You can also specify a host name or IP pattern, for example:

```
$ ht ssh 192.168.17.[1-99] /data/reports/formatted_report.sh
$ ht ssh host[00-99] /data/reports/formatted_report.sh
```

It also supports a `--random-start-delay <millis>` option that will delay the start of the command on each host by a random time interval between 0 and `<millis>` milliseconds. This option can be used to avoid thundering herd problems when the command being run accesses a central resource.